# ¿Como controlar el evento "al presionar ENTER" en JOption Pane Java?

Tags: java, botón, eventos, interfaz

Estoy creando una aplicación CRUD (create, read, update, delete) de escritorio en Java con Netbeans.

La idea es que cuando uno apriete el botón guardar al presionar Enter, el sistema arroje un cuadro de dialogo con el aviso de carga satisfactoria, o bien, error en la carga de datos. El problema se genera al presionar la tecla Enter para dar el ok al aviso del JOptionPane, ya que el boton guardar (btnGuardar) tambien tiene asociado el evento "al presionar Enter", y eso genera que al darle guardar vuelva a aparecer el cuadro de dialogo del JOptionPane.

**No es una opción hacer foco en otros widgets, ya que las demás cajas de texto y botones tambien tienen eventos asociados a la tecla Enter.**

¿Como se podria solucionar este problema? Voy a poner un ejemplo burdo para que se entienda el problema.

```
private void btnGuardarKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
               obtenerDatos();
               //Aca se ejecuta el codigo del boton
        }
}

public Registro obtenerDatos(){
        Registro reg = new Registro();           //Genero el objeto de tipo Registro
        
        if (txtNombre.getText().isEmpty()==false){

              reg.setNombre(txtNombre.getText());      //Aca se recuperan los datos de la interfaz
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Carga exitosa","Aviso", 
              JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
              
        }else{
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Inserte al menos un carácter","Error", 
              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Comment: Hola tengo el mismo problema, pudiste solucionar?

Answer (score 0):

en html
puedes probar

<input matInput (keyup.enter)="metodo()">

y de lado de js o ts

metodo(){
"Instrucciones del metodo"
}

Comment: Hola! esto es Java, no JS... gracias igual!